# If Statement fails when I input a del into it

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, delete-file

This might be a simple problem, but I'm new to writing batch files. Basically, when I run the code like this:

```
IF EXIST %ExportFile1% (
echo test1 >> %log_dir%
pause
) ELSE (
echo test2 >> %log_dir%
pause)
```

The %ExportFile1% just points to a local file. If I run the code with del added, the batch file seems to fail using:

```
SET do_stuff=false
IF EXIST %ExportFile1% (
echo test1 >> %log_dir%
del %GDriveFile1%
pause
) ELSE (
echo test2 >> %log_dir%
pause)
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: spaces? `del "%GDriveFile1%"`

Comment: show the value of `%GDriveFile1%` if its value has brackets or spaces this could lead to failure .

Comment: I'll have a look into that. Thank you.